# mysql client ran out of memory because SELECT query repeatedly returns the same rows

Tags: mysql

For example, the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table
```

returns 231,146 as the number of rows in the table and the query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table r WHERE r.column1=0 AND r.column2=0 LIMIT 250000
```

returns 250,000 rows.  This only occurs for specific values of column1 and column2, and it appears that three rows end up repeating forever.

Edit: No matter what I set the LIMIT to in the second query it would end up trying to return that many rows, so if the query was unbounded by LIMIT it would end up returning enough rows to run out of memory.

Comment: do you really need to select 250k rows at once? I doubt so. Also, not knowing your schema and content of the DB it's hard to say what you do wrong.

Comment: The first query returns exactly one row.

Comment: he got 2 queries in question

Comment: Sorry, the first query returns 1 row, but it says the table has 231,146 rows

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simple mysqlcheck repair didn't work, but running this ended up repairing the table:

REPAIR TABLE my_table EXTENDED;